# "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SharePointTools" doesnot show up in registry

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to make changes to the registry entry at -

```
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SharePointTools".
```

But the SharePointTools does not show up in my registry.

I do have Sharepoint 2010 installed on my machine. 
Would there be any settings changes or any reason it does not show up.

Comment: Create the key, change it & see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of key should be the same for any user.  So it is stored in HKLM, not in HKCU.  Also watch out for a 64-bit operating system, Visual Studio is a 32-bit program so the key is stored in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SharePointTools.  Note the added Wow6432Node.